# How to find if my idea for a machine that I have created, worths patenting it?

Tags: patentability

My question is very simple, I have an idea, I constructed the machine, it works. Now, the question is does it worth patenting it? I mean, the amount of money in order to patent is not little for me where I live (EU country). Moreover every year (for the next 20 years) I should pay an amount of money that increases in every year..! So, how can I find out if the market is going to buy the machine (the patent) I thought of??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually a very hard question. It is also probably off topic as it is really a business question rather than a patent question. Regardless, I'll give you a few thoughts.

First, your machine may or may not be patentable. Just because you don't see it in the market doesn't mean someone hasn't already patented it. It might not even be considered sufficiently inventive. You should try searching for similar technologies on [Google Patents](https://patents.google.com/) or [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/). This takes some work and there are answers on this site related to doing patent searching.

I have worked for startup companies. Valuation is maybe the biggest question. You have to predict sales, manufacturing and sales expenses, etc. to figure this out and there is no way we can help with this. A lot of inventors team up with business people with startup experience. You don't need a patent to do this, but you should have a non-disclosure agreement with whoever you show your machine to. If you get investors then you can use that money to pursue a patent.

Comment: What google patents website shows are International patents or on each country (national) ?

Comment: Google Patents searches internationally. The Lens is also international and makes it easy to pick specifically which countries to search. You should search widely since if a patent exists in any country, it presents prior art and would keep you from getting a patent on the same invention.

Answer (score 0):

value is in the eye of the buyer, no one can give an answer which is either yes it is worth patent or no it is not worth patent. worth is not only dependent on the idea alone, it also depends on what you do with the idea (patent it and make a business out of it, license it or wait for someone to approach you with funding), how the market receives your idea etc.

This is more of a business question than patent related so you take a decision.

Comment: Please consider improving this answer as it has been flagged by a user as low quality. It really isn't true that no one can give an answer about product value. Businesses do this all the time. What is true is that we on this site can't provide an answer since that would require disclosure which would preclude patenting.

Comment: It really isn't true that no one can give an answer about product value. Businesses do this all the time- this is only their understanding of worth but not actual. If someone can give product worth before the launch of the product then there will not be any flop products in the market (no one wants to launch worthless product)

Comment: This is not looking like a community, only if we agree to Eric idealogy or understanding then it is good otherwise answer will be flagged as low value.

Comment: I’m trying to be helpful. People are flagging your answers. As moderator, I end up having to deal with flagged answers. I’m trying to avoid closing answers by providing feedback which allows you and others to improve. I do believe you have a lot to contribute, but that doesn’t mean your content can’t be improved.